# How to gen other certs like "PeerAdmin" with composer identity import

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I clone the **fabric-dev-server** and run the sample project successfully.
But I do not know what is `creds` folder and how to create the files in this folder.

There is a private key, a public key and a config json file with certificate.

I tried to use the `composer identity import` but nothing happend.
Then I copied the private key, use openssl export the public key from cert, write the `PeerAdmin` file manually, and it works!

So can I use the `composer identity composer`  instead that works I do manually? Or other commands ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The creds directory contains the contents of an already imported (using the `composer identity import` command) crypto material that represents a channel admin and admin for the peer of the development fabric server provided by the fabric-dev-server package.

Unfortunately a problem was introduced into the command line identity import in 0.10.1 and also exists in 0.11.0 and it is currently not working. 
The API to import identities still works and you can downgrade composer-cli to 0.10.0 to run this command to work around the problem for now until the command is fixed in the next release.